# Is there a way to programatically popup the "Microsoft Silverlight Configuration" dialog?

Tags: silverlight, configuration, silverlight-4.0, contextmenu

I am building for Silverlight 4, and I handle MouseRightButtonDown events and build my own ContextMenu's (a class from the Silverlight Toolkit).  I would like to add the classic "**Silverlight**" menu item to my menus, and give the user the familiar option of launching the "**Microsoft Silverlight Configuration**" dialog.  This is the dialog lets users manage Updates, Webcams, Permissions, and Application Storage.  So I need a way to programatically launch the dialog when the menu item is clicked.

I can be done for Flash, and it would seem that Microsoft would want to encourage developers to support that option.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer no likes to give: no.  Currently there is no exposure in the Silverlight API to invoke the display of the Silverlight configuration dialog.

I would agree that such a feature ought to exist.

**Edit**

In response to your additional question.  In an elevated SL4 OOB app it may be possible to get the scripting shell to launch the `Silverlight.Configuration.exe`.   You find this file at:-

> %programfiles%\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.50401.0\Silverlight.Configuration.exe

Comment: @AnthonyWJones - I noticed today that Silverlight Spy (http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy) has a Tools >> Silverlight Configuratoin menu item that launches the dialog.  I know that this is a WPF application and not a Silverlight control, but I am curious how the dialog is lauched in that case.  Maybe this could be done OOB and/or via COM?  I'd love to learn more...

Comment: @Jim:  Edited answer with the additional info you requested

Answer (score 0):

Note that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645084(v=vs.95).aspx says:

> Users can also access this dialog box from the Microsoft Silverlight folder on the Start menu or 
>   through a configuration application. On Windows, this application is found in one of the following 
>   locations:
>
> On 32-bit operating systems: C:\Program Files\Microsoft 
>   Silverlight\versionNumber\Silverlight.Configuration.exe
>
> On 64-bit operating systems: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
>   Silverlight\versionNumber\Silverlight.Configuration.exe
>
> On Macintosh computers, users can access the configuration application by following these steps:
>   1. In Finder, navigate to /Library/Internet Plug-Ins.
>
> 1. Right-click (or press CTRL and then click) Silverlight.plugin and then select Show package contents.
> 2. Navigate to Contents/Resources and then double-click Silverlight.Preferences.app.

From what I understand you can have Elevated Trust OOB apps on Mac OS X too (to access the filesystem), but not sure if that gives you a way to launch some local app or you need COM interop which is only available for Silverlight Elevated Trust apps on Windows (either OOB or in-browser too with Silverlight 5)